# How do I access all available event color keys that are available in the CalendarContract.EventColumn?

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to work with the CalendarContract class provided by Google for Android. I've hit a block trying to figure out how to access which colors I can apply to an event. You can see a list of colors you can apply to an event if you go to the add event screen on either Android's Calendar app or on the web-version of the Google calendar.

I can see there is a list of available colors to choose from, and I want to know if there is a way to get that list programmatically. I don't want to assume I can add any color I want.

One thing I've tested when adding an event is just passing in a random int using the ContentValues object:

```
ContentValues l_event = new ContentValues();
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventName);
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "This is test event");
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "UCLA");
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());

l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY, 1);

Uri l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
Uri l_uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(l_eventUri, l_event);
```

I tried playing around with the line

```
l_event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY, 1);
```

by passing in different integers. It looks like lower values work, like 1 and 2 (I get different event colors with those values). But if I pass in 100, it breaks. This is where I'm trying to make this work. I want to know how to query the Calendar so I know how many colors I have to work with.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar colors for `CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY` column:

```
Color ID    Color Name  Hex Code
1           Lavender    #7986cb
2           Sage        #33b679
3           Grape       #8e24aa
4           Flamingo    #e67c73
5           Banana      #f6c026
6           Tangerine   #f5511d
7           Peacock     #039be5
8           Graphite    #616161
9           Blueberry   #3f51b5
10          Basil       #0b8043
11          Tomato      #d60000
```